# MariaDB LIMIT statement brings more than limit

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, limit

I have 10,000 users on `registrations` table and want to limit this query to  3500 users from my application. But when I investigate the logs , sometimes it counts more than 3500. I can not understand why that query returns more than limit:

```
select  count(*)
    from  registrations
    where  (selectedtime IS NULL
       AND  expirationtime < NOW()
           )
    LIMIT  3500;
```

I tried manually on DB and saw sometimes more than 3500

Comment: There's only 1 row in the output. That's less than 3500.

Comment: I mean it counts more than 3500. I said wrong, i am sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Your query only returns 1 row, which is less than 3500.

If you want to limit the number of rows that are being counted, you need to put that in a subquery.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT 1
    FROM registrations
    WHERE selectedtime IS NULL AND expirationtime < NOW()
    LIMIT 3500) AS x
```

Comment: I ran your query and saw counted number didnt go more than 3500 but why my query counts more than 3500 ?

Comment: The LIMIT specifies the maximum number of rows in the results of that query. How many rows were in the results of your query?

Comment: It limits the number of rows returned, not the number of rows processed, unless there's a direct correspondence between them.

Comment: Oh, I understand. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

A SELECT statement with COUNT returns the number of rows retrieved by the SELECT statement.

For performance reasons, the desired result is to limit that count.
Including a LIMIT clause in the SELECT statement will not work since it only restricts the number of rows returned, which is always one.

The solution, what I call “Limited-Count”, is done by limiting a non-count SELECT statement and wrapping it in COUNT(*).

For example:
If your count statement looks like

```
select count(*) from registrations where (selectedtime IS NULL AND expirationtime < NOW()) LIMIT 3500;
```

You can limit the results by replacing the query into:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
FROM (
    SELECT 1
    FROM registrations
    WHERE selectedtime IS NULL AND expirationtime < NOW()
    LIMIT 3500) AS x
```

If you need to know how many rows your non-count SELECT statement would have returned without the LIMIT, you could use the information function, FOUND_ROWS(). It will fetch the total rows number without running the statement again.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you *thought* you were doing:

```
select  count(*)
    from  registrations
    where  (selectedtime IS NULL
       AND  expirationtime < NOW()
           )
    LIMIT ROWS EXAMINED 3500;
```

(Available since MariaDB 5.5.21 - see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/limit-rows-examined/ )